# How to block external http header 302 redirect apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, external

I cannot block an external http header 302 redirect from pointing to my website.

I have tried all the .htaccess redirect rules. I don't have access to the http conf file, my web host assures me this cannot be done, but cannot help me block this external http header.

This is the code from the external http header:

```
`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily =>`
`Date => Fri, 21 Sep 2012 07:35:15 GMT`
`Server => Apache`
`X-Powered-By => PHP/5.3.16`
`Expires => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT`
`Cache-Control => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0`
`Pragma => no-cache`
`Set-Cookie => osCsid=eidbr9o47qqcjap8el0ck5la67; path=/; domain=http://nastydomain.co.uk`
`Location => http://www.mydomain.co.uk/`
`Connection => close`
`Content-Type => text/html`
```

Google has now spidered the website and it now looks like there are two sites with duplicate content. Google.co.uk has also said they won't do anything about this site unless I get a court order.

Any ideas how I can block 302 redirects to my site?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum30/28329-24-30.htm displays at the last 2 posts the only defense you can undertake but it's still ineffective.

The best way is legal(if you have a business you should also have a legal insurance) or contact google via spam reporting or the site removal tool.

**-- EDIT --**

Best solution what I can think of:
Since the spammer uses a 302 redirect:

Go to google's webmaster tools, put the spammers site into your webmasters tool. Get the verification code, place it in the HTML code of the page he links to(your main index in this case), run the site verification and it should take it.

When it's verfied move to "block" the site from google's index.

Added bonus, you now have control over all the indexing of that domain for the future. BRING ON THE HURT! ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I have already contacted the hosting company and they also said that I need to get a court order to stop this.

Comment: just out of curiosity could you provide the "bad" domain that is doing this?

Comment: Tried $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  - nothing was displayed.

Comment: Let me know how it works out, because that would help a LOT of webmasters facing this issue

Comment: I've managed to request removal in Webmaster Tools, now all I have to do is wait - thanks very much!

Comment: That is great news. Google will think it's yours because you verified it. That way it'll stop bugging your seo ranking. Good to know that's a solution. If it gets axed by google, please consider accepting my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try block the referer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} nastydomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} www.nastydomain\.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Update: If the one above doesn't work for you, you can block by using deny, allow directives and using env. See [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env]:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://(www.)?nastydomain.com" bad_domain=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://casino-poker.com" bad_domain=1

<FilesMatch "(.*)"> 
Order Allow,Deny 
Allow from all 
Deny from env=bad_domain
</FilesMatch>
```

There might be a performance penalty using this in as the domain name has to be looked up.

Comment: I have tried that, doesn't work - it's a .co.uk domain - would it be like this: www.nastydomain\.co\.uk ? Cause I have tried that too.

Comment: I tried that, I added it to the top of the .htaccess and then tried it elsewhere in the .htaccess - didn't work....

Comment: Hmmm. I assume you have restarted or forced-reloading the server after each change. Is your .htaccess file honoured or is there any AllowOverride directive preventing it from being read?

Comment: I have cleared my browser cache, tried the other browsers, cleared their cache. In the website file system, there is an .htaccess and then there is one in the public folder. I have tried the code in both of files - not at the same time. The .htaccess in the public folder has some wordpress rewrite rules that are working....

Answer (score 0):

Since he is sending his domain name in a cookie, try this in the beginning of your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} nastydomain\.co\.uk
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```